# Симуляция нажатия клавиши клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, клавиатура, tampermonkey

Представим, что есть вот такой input на сайте: `input placeholder="Введи e-mail" name="username" type="email" class="sg-input sg-input--full-width" value=""`,который предназначен для ввода почты.
Я даю этому полю любое значение, но кнопка отвечающая за завершение регистрации 
**не будет активной** пока я не введу любой символ в input через **клавиатуру**. И тут встает задача - симулировать нажатие клавиши, я перепробовал разные способы, например через dispatchEvent, но это не дало результатов. Не могли бы вы мне помочь с этим?

Comment: Не работает, поле становится заполненным, но кнопка не активна до тех пор, пока я не введу любой символ в input через клавиатуру.

Comment: А если disabled=false кнопке? Или сразу слать сообщение на сервер какое вам нужно?)

Comment: Попробуйте такой ивент задиспатчить. `const e = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```
element.setAttribute('value', 'email@gmail.com')
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));
```

Comment: Вау! Это сработало, я пытался реализовать это дней 5, спасибо вам большое

Comment: `document.querySelector('[data-test="submit"]').classList.remove('sg-button--disabled');` у меня так вроде сработало в паре с `disabled=false`

Comment: @Leonid, да кнопка становится активной, но при нажатии на нее вроде ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант нужен?

```js
$('#text').on('input', function(){ // При вводе в input#text, делаем следующее:
  $('#submit') // берём input#submit
    .prop('disabled', $(this).val().length > 0 ? false : true); // Если символов в input#text больше 0, то делаем кнопку input#submit - активной, если нет, то неактивной.
});
 
$('#submit').on('click', function(){ // при нажатии на input#submit выполняем следующее:
  if($(this).prop('disabled') === false) { // если кнопка активна, то выполняем следующее
    alert('Отправлено');
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="text" type="text" value="" placeholder="Введите текст">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить" disabled>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваши старания, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Такая кнопка уже существует и мне нужно ее как-то обмануть, т.е. отправить в input нажатие клавиши клавиатуры